# Element of a list use as a variable in R?

Tags: r

I have a list of elements:

```
E.list <- list("ELP","ARC","DEG","UEG","BAC")
```

And I want to use them as a variable as well as a pattern in `grepl` such as:

```
ELP <- df[, grepl("ELP", names(df))]
ELP_META <- dplyr::filter(Meta, grepl("ELP", CASE_Name))
ARC <- df[, grepl("ARC", names(df))]
ARC_META <- dplyr::filter(Meta, grepl("ARC", CASE_Name))
.
.
.
```

How I can do it using `for` loop or `foreach`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may extract the element of the `list` with `[[`

```
df[, grepl(E.list[[1]], names(df))]
```

If we need to loop

```
out <- lapply(E.list, function(nm) {
       tmp <- df[, grepl(nm, names(df))]
       tmp_META <- dplyr::filter(Meta, grepl(nm, CASE_Name))
        return(setNames(list(tmp, tmp_META), c(nm, paste0(nm, "_META"))))

       })
```

In a `for` loop we can do

```
out <- vector('list', length(E.list))
out_META <- vector('list', length(E.list))
names(out) <- E.list
names(out_META) <- paste0(E.list, "_META")
for(nm in E.list) {
     out[[nm]] <- df[, grepl(nm, names(df))]
     out_META[[paste0(nm, "_META")]] <- dplyr::filter(Meta, grepl(nm, CASE_Name))
}
```

If the intention is to create multiple objects in the global env, it is not recommended, instead store it in a `list` as in the above solutions.  But, if we use `assign` it would create those objects

```
for(nm in E.list) {
    assign(nm, df[, grepl(nm, names(df))]
   assign(paste0(nm, "_META"), dplyr::filter(Meta, grepl(nm, CASE_Name)))
}
```

Comment: And how I can call these variables in this loop for further functions such as:
`for(nm in E.list) {
   assign(nm, df[, grepl(nm, names(df))])
   assign(paste0(nm, "_META"), dplyr::filter(Meta, grepl(nm, CASE_Name)))
   assign(paste0("dgFull.", nm), DFList(counts = nm, 
                                         samples = nm_META,
                                         group = nm_META$Condition))
}`
is it applicable or need some modification?

Comment: @Mendel you can extend the loop as you wish.  i.e. in the for loop after the line `out_META[[paste0(nm, "_META")]] <- dplyr::filter(Meta, grepl(nm, CASE_Name))` add your other functions

Comment: @Mendel the reason I mentioned to store in list is to avoid creating those objects in the global env.  In the for loop with `assign`, you can just call `ELP` or `ELP_META` and  apply the function because these objects are created in the global env.  whereas in the `list` i.e. you can loop over the list and apply the funcitons `lapply(out, yourfunc); lapply(out_META, yourfunc)`